# Why Kotlin Coroutine Global scope with Main thread gives exception?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Here is the code, i try to run but it gives me exception.

exception generates only in `Dispatchers.Main` scope, if i try to use io or default it works properly, no exceptions.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        
        println(" Program Starts to run")
        
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            delay(2000)
            println("Program inside global scope launch")
        }
    
        println(" Program Ends Now")
    }
```

Exception is::

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while
> trying to handle coroutine exception  at
> kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerKt.handlerException(CoroutineExceptionHandler.kt:38)

I tried to search out this in Google but not find particular answer on it.

Comment: Need more info to be able to reproduce this. Where do you call this code in your project?

Comment: @Tenfour04 please check now. i have run on main function only

Comment: The `main` function is not used on Android. And if you aren't using Android, Swing, JavaFX, or Compose Multiplatform, then there is no `Dispatchers.Main` because there is no designated main thread.